# IOS calling a number and enter a code

Tags: ios, phone-call

I want to create a app that will call a number and after a few seconds enter a code. Is this even possible? I searched all over and couldn't find anything about accessing the phone.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically Dial a Phone number and pass DTMF using the iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584663/programatically-dial-a-phone-number-and-pass-dtmf-using-the-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible, at least via code.
You can use the tel: url schema to call the number.

then use the 'p' for a pauze:

```
tel:+145555464p123
```

Comment: So by doing this i will pause the phone call for 123 seconds but i can't enter the code.No?

Comment: Yes, it will call the number then pauze and call 123.

Comment: I found this link after you sent me in the right direction .Thanks for all the help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584663/programatically-dial-a-phone-number-and-pass-dtmf-using-the-iphone-sdk/4943272#4943272

Comment: Keep in mind that this will require the user's consent. The user will be presented with the number and be asked if they want to call it. If you're trying to do this without the user's consent, well... don't.

Comment: There will be an alert and the user can choose if he want to dial or cancel.

Answer (score 2):

You can dial the number with pauses.

If you insert a comma between the phone number and the code you want to dial, it will dial the number, pause, then dial the code.

Other than that, there isn't a way to gain access to the call or phone audio.

**Edit** I think rckoenes is correct, you should use a p.
[Inserting a pause into a tel:// link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765777/inserting-a-pause-into-a-tel-link)

Comment: Could you please give me an example or maybe a link to more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had to accept rckoenes answer but you helped me also.Thanks anyway .