# how to make phone call in Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: iphone, android, flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

i am developing an application for andriod and iphone in the Adobe Flash Builder,how can i make a button that when is pressed the phone(doesnt matter which phone) forwards the number to the phones dialer or makes it VOIP call, thanks in advance :)

Comment: may i know which language you are using?

Comment: you program in Flash Builder in action script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like the tel link: [Inserting a pause into a tel:// link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765777/inserting-a-pause-into-a-tel-link)

I've not tried it, but putting this into the `htmlText` of a `TextField` and clicking on it should work

Android has a similar functionality I think:
http://androidforums.com/android-applications/31225-possible-make-link-telephone-number.html

[Android WebView "tel:" links show web page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338305/android-webview-tel-links-show-web-page-not-found)